# Аналог функции TODAY() в Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Моя цель - сделать так, чтобы при добавлении информации в строку, в определенной ячейке, появлялась текущая дата в формате день/год/месяц. Но, требуется, чтобы дата больше не менялась, а функции NOW,TODAY - функции пересчитываемые. В справке Microsoft по Google Tables В разделе "Дата и Время" не нашёл нужной мне функции. Оная существует или вопрос можно решить только макросом/скриптом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Специальной функции нет, но

> вопрос можно решить только макросом/скриптом

Например, так:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  // Действует только для определённого листа книги
  // и для всех колонок, кроме A
  if (sheet.getName() == 'Лист1' && e.range.getColumn() > 1) {
    // текущее дата-время заносим в колонку A
    sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 1).setValue(new Date());
    // Формат "день/год/месяц" настраиваем из меню для всей колонки A
  }
}
```

А вот и требуемая настройка формата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Получаю следующее сообщение об ошибке: [https://ibb.co/LC04yNr]

Comment: Подробнее, если можно. Ваша ссылка приводит к сообщению 404 (эта страница не найдена). Между тем, в моей таблице приведённый выше код проверен.

Comment: C этим разобрался, поторопился. "Лист 1" заменил на название листа из своей таблицы. Также сделал так, чтобы при определенных значениях, в любой ячейке столбца, выставлялась дата в нужном мне столбце. Например, в столбце B: при значении "тест1" - дата пишется в столбец А, а при значение "тест2" - дата пишется в столбце C. Всё работает, но только если записывать значения вручную. При копировании или перетягивании(надеюсь, что понимаете, о чём я) мой скрипт не работает. Не подскажете, в чём может быть причина?

Comment: onEdit - стандартный обработчик события изменения данных в ячейках - действует действительно лишь после ручного редактирования. Если копирование идет вручную, onEdit тоже работает. Но если обработка данных производится скриптом или формулами (то есть автоматизирована), onEdit не будет вызван. Значит, в ходе автоматизированных изменений надо предусмотреть фиксацию даты и времени также автоматически.

Comment: Подскажете в какую сторону копать, чтобы реализовать это?

Comment: "реализовать это"? Что именно? Приведите свой код, свой фрагмент таблицы, скриншот... Поставьте конкретную цель. Я же не могу угадать смысл Ваших действий.

Comment: Код, фрагмент таблицы, скриншот - всё это уже есть в вашем ответе. Конкретная цель - "в ходе автоматизированных изменений надо предусмотреть фиксацию даты и времени также автоматически"

Comment: Так вот и хотелось бы увидеть Ваш (!) код с этими автоматизированными изменениями, в ходе которых мы будем фиксировать дату и время. Причем делать это мы будем точно так же: sheet.getRange(...).setValue(new Date());

Comment: Код:

`function onEdit(e) {
  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if (sheet.getName() == 'DB' && e.range.getColumn() == 6 && e.value=="Склад") {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 7).setValue(new Date());
    }
  
  if (sheet.getName() == 'DB' && e.range.getColumn() == 6 && e.value==("Продажа" || "Аренда" || "Тест" || "Замена")) {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 8).setValue(new Date());
    }
  }`

[https://ibb.co/4gVKJ1q](https://ibb.co/4gVKJ1q) - фрагмент таблицы.

Comment: Всё же onEdit? Значит ожидаемые изменения производятся вручную. А не работало, как я понимаю, из-за неправильной проверки значений e.value. Вот исправленный код: function onEdit(e) {
 var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet(); 
 if (sheet.getName() == 'DB' && e.range.getColumn() == 6 && e.value=="Склад") { 
  sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 7).setValue(new Date()); 
 }
    
 if (sheet.getName() == 'DB' && e.range.getColumn() == 6 && ["Продажа", "Аренда", "Тест", "Замена"].indexOf(e.value) > -1) { 
  sheet.getRange(e.range.getRow(), 8).setValue(new Date()); 
 } 
}

Comment: Код, который я прислал - работает, выше я упоминал об этом. Мне нужны именно автоматизированные изменения. И я пытаюсь выяснить как это сделать. Как я понял, нужна другая функция вместо onEdit. Какая?

Comment: Teddy, назовите функцию иначе (не onEdit) и пусть она изменит Ваши данные в колонке 6 так, как Вам требуется. И пусть она сработает автоматически - по таймеру, что ли. Меню: "Edit" - "Current Project Triggers" - "Add Trigger" - и так далее. Вы ведь ни разу не сказали, когда она должна сработать и что, и где она должна изменить. А как обсуждать автоматизацию, если мы даже этого не знаем?

Comment: Цель - сделать так, чтобы дата в столбце  7 и 8 менялась и в том случае, если данные из столбца 6 копируются или заполняются перетягиванием, а не только при вводе вручную. То бишь, необходима, как я понимаю, модернизация кода или использование каких-то дополнительных инструментов.

Comment: Стоп! Осталось выяснить, что такое "перетягивание". Вы делаете это вручную? Как именно? Если имеется ввиду автозаполнение диапазона (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/75509?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=ru), то это - вручную, и предложенный вариант кода УЖЕ фиксирует дату и время изменения после таких действий. Тогда почему возвращаемся к пройденному?

Comment: Да, имеется в виду автозаполнение. Предложенный вариант кода не фиксирует дату и время после автозаполнения или копирования. В этом, собственно, суть проблемы.

Comment: Итак, добрались до сути. СОГЛАСЕН, код требует доработки. Доработал. Предлагаю ознакомиться здесь - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6fcDDFhGDAnZeEF5dP3BkvHisajIohbCmneBdB3WUQ/edit?usp=sharing - (временный доступ).